# getting syntax error in compiling fortran code

Tags: fortran

I am trying to run some old Fortran code of my project team in ubuntu 14.04. I have not done any modifications to the existing code. All I have done is installed gfortran, opened a terminal, and gone to the file location using the cd command. Here I have many files, but just consider this `table.f` file

I am trying to compile the following old fortran code using f77 (fort77 compiler).

```
SUBROUTINE table(FACTOR, PRR, TRR)
IMPLICIT NONE
INCLUDE'../SOURCES_COUNTERFLOW/unsteadyf_inc.h'
  DOUBLE PRECISION PRR, TRR, FACTOR, Y  
  DOUBLE PRECISION A01, B01, A02, B02  
  A01 = .038042d0; B01 = 1.52267d0
  A02 = .067433d0; B02 = 2.16794d0
  IF(TRR .LE. 1.0d0) THEN
     TRR = 1.0d0
     GO TO 10
  ENDIF
10 CONTINUE
  IF(PRR .LT. 0.2d0) Y = 1.01d0 * (1.0d0 - A01 * TRR**(-B01))
  IF(PRR .GE. 5.0d0) 
 &        Y = 1.07d0 * (1.0d0 - A50*TRR**(-B50))
  FACTOR = Y
  RETURN
  END
```

I get the following error.

```
f77 -f -o ../SOURCES_COUNTERFLOW/table.o -c ../SOURCES_COUNTERFLOW/table.f
table:
Error on line 6: syntax error
Error on line 7: syntax error
/usr/bin/f77: aborting compilation
make: *** [../SOURCES_COUNTERFLOW/table.o] Error 25
```

Please help me to figure out the problem.

Comment: Your error message states that the syntax issues are on lines 24 and 25, but you've included fewer than 20 lines of code.  I recommend you give this article a careful read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @PaulH, sorry for the mistake, please check the edited code.

Comment: So I've never written fortran code from scratch, but I notice you define two different variables on each of those lines. Did you try anything? Perhaps assigning only 1 variable per line without the semicolons?

Comment: @PaulH the `;` is equivalent to a line break, so each line is effectively two lines.

Comment: I also don't think you gave the article I linked a careful read. Your example still includes a reference to a header file that no one but you has. As a result, people can't try to compile this themselves without an error from the missing header, which is a different issue than the one you're trying to solve here

Comment: Problem looks more like a discrepancy between so called free formatted code and fixed formatted code. How many spaces are in the front of each line? Furthermore you use f77 as compiler. You didn't state which compiler you use, but I would say a better choice would be gfortran directly (f77 might use under the hood gfortran as well)

Comment: f77 interprets `.f` files [as fixed-format](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4941/6j4m2soav/index.html), whereas your code is free-format. Try the `-free` flag, or renaming `table.f` to `table.f90`?

Comment: Are you sure the code is free format? `IF(PRR .GE. 5.0d0) 
 &        Y = 1.07d0 * (1.0d0 - A50*TRR**(-B50))` looks more to me like something that was originally fixed format, and then things have got screwed up somehow. But it could be either. Also count me as another for not using f77 and instead invoking whatever the Fortran compiler is directly

Comment: This is not Fortran 77 code and isn't something a Fortran 77 compiler can be expected to understand.

Comment: So did you actually succeed to get your compilation  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579566/make-f90-command-not-found going on? What happened when you used `gfortran`? Why does `f77 -v` print?

Comment: @IanBush, My code compiled. As you mentioned I used gfortran executable directly.

Comment: The `;` isn't a valid syntax to separate statements. Try splitting into separate lines the assignment into `A01`, `B01`, `A02`, `B02`.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou, thanks for your reply. Separate lines without `;` worked.

Comment: @MohammedNiyasdeen - I am glad. Please put the changes in an answer and award it yourself.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou `;` is perfectly valid for separating statements since Fortran 90. The obsolete compiler did not understand it, but that is not the fault of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the syntax error issue by splitting the statements `A01` `B01` `A02` `B02` in separate lines.

Comment: Note that since Fortran 90, separating multiple statements on one source line using `;` is perfectly legal. Even in the fixed source form (.f files). Gfortran should have no problem compiling this. The problem is in using a hopelessly obsolete compiler.

Comment: @VladimirF, Thanks for your reply. I completely understand.